# What is the strategy to win Tug of War game by relating with Newton's Law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

What is the strategy to win Tug of War game by relating with Newton's Law

Comment: Use sticky shoes and stay as horizontal as you can to prevent rotation

Comment: Work out, eat green leafy vegetables and increase your inertia

Answer (score 2):

Pull harder than the other team.